# Eigenvectors of contraction times projection

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvector, eigenvalues

Suppose $A$ is a real $n\times n$ matrix  with real eigenvalues:
$$
1=\lambda_1>|\lambda_2|\ge \ldots\ge |\lambda_n|>0.
$$
Suppose $B$ is an involution, for simplicity let us assume that 
$B$ is diagonal, has $k$ ones on the diagonal,  and $n-k$ minus ones.
Suppose I also know that $AB$ has an eigenvector $ABx=x$.
Thus I know that 
$$
ABx=x,\quad Ay=y
$$
for some $y$.

Can I conclude that $A(I+B)/2$ has eigenvalue $1$ as well, ie.
$$
A\cdot \frac {I+B}{2} z=z
$$
for some $z$?

Comment: Is the $\leq$ after $|\lambda_2|$ a typo for $>$?